# Pushed commit without pulling before

Tags: git, merge, push

I accidentially pushed a commit without pulling before. So I didn‘t merge a commit a Team member pushed before.
I‘m sure I didn‘t get a conflict warning, but how can I merge this commit now in my current development state?

Comment: May you explain the branches involved? If you pushed a shared branch and it didn't require a pull first, then the other contributors will need to pull first.

Comment: Just pull. You're overthinking this.

Comment: The funny thing is that if the other dev already pushed, then you should not have been able to push.... _unless_ you force-pushed. Did you?

Comment: I‘m working in a branch the Team member committed into. I‘m a newbie but (unfortunately) admin. This might be the reason I was able to push without a conflict. I‘m pretty sure I did no force push. But How can I merge this now?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be an admin, you'll need to learn how Git works.  For now though, rest assured that if you didn't use `git push -f` or `git push --force` or equivalent,<sup>1</sup> you did nothing wrong, and a pull first would have made no difference.

It's not clear from your StackOverflow user info what you might already know about graph theory, but, once you've mastered some simple local committing, you should read through the [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) web site.  It also helps to know the following:

- Git is really all about *commits*.  Branches—or more precisely, branch *names;* it's important to remember that humans (and Git) overuse the word *branch* to the point where it becomes practically meaningless sometimes—are just a way to *find* commits.  Commits themselves have True Names that are big ugly hash IDs.  They look random and are impossible for humans to work with, so we don't: we use names, like branch names and tag names, instead.  The true names—the hash IDs—never change, because they're actually the result of doing a cryptographic hash on the *contents* of the commit.

  Git uses hash IDs internally.  The `git log` command shows them.  They're the real names.  But we—and Git—use the *branch* names to find the *hash IDs*.  Each branch name holds *one* hash ID.
- *Branch names* are local to one particular repository.  Cloning a repository copies *all of its commits*<sup>2</sup> and *none of its branch names*.<sup>3</sup>  Once the commits exist in the new clone, `git clone` creates one *new* branch name in the new clone.  This one new branch name holds the *same* hash ID as the name your Git found in their Git: for instance, if you `git clone -b leeloo <url>`, your Git looks for the `leeloo` branch name in *their* Git. That represents some particular commit, by hash ID.  Your Git then creates *your own* `leeloo` name, using the *same* hash ID they're using right now.

  The hash IDs stored in branch names change over time.  Adding a new commit means updating a name.  The names in your Git hold the *latest* commit hash IDs, for each of your branches.  The same is true in every other Git repository too.
- `git pull` is actually a convenience command, built out of two more-basic commands.  One of these is the *get me any new commits they have* command: `git fetch` has your Git call up some other Git repository, find out what commits they have that you don't, and bring those commits over.  (Clone in fact is mainly just a fetch into an empty repository.)  It's this `git fetch` that is as close as we get to the opposite of `git push`.  The `pull` command has the wrong name, for historical reasons.

  (Having run `git fetch`, `git pull` then runs a second Git command to *incorporate* the fetched commits.  You usually will want to do that eventually; `git pull` makes you do it *immediately*, which is sometimes too soon.  But since you usually want it eventually anyway, having it done immediately is sometimes convenient.  But this second command can go wrong, and it's important to realize that you *choose* which second command to use, and the things you must do after it *does* go wrong, depend on that choice.)

  The fetch command is safe to use any time, because all it does is get new commits *from* some other Git.  Your own commits on your own branches are *entirely unaffected* by this.  Your branches are *yours:* they won't be touched by new commits someone else added to *their* branches.

  The *second* command that `pull` runs is *not* so safe, regardless of which one you pick, though they're all intended to be nondestructive.<sup>4</sup>
- `git push` is the command that sends new commits from your Git repository to some other Git repository.  This one is tricky because unlike `git fetch`, it ends by asking or commanding that other Git repository to *set* some of its branch(es), depending on what you tell `git push` to push *to*.  Since they find commits by their branches, you can tell them to *lose* commits.  This is where the `--force` options come into effect: without them, the other Git will tell you "no", if you ask it to do something that would lose commits.  *With* `--force`, the final step of `git push` is a command rather than a polite request, and if you have the right privileges—admin access for instance—they'll generally obey.

You'll need to learn all about how commits connect backwards to older commits, and how `git merge` and `git rebase` work.  Those are the two standard second commands for `git pull`.  Both are complex, though rebase is much more complicated than merge (because rebase is mostly repeated cherry-picking, and each cherry-pick is a form of merging).  Most of this is nicely covered in the web site I linked above.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can set a per-refspec force flag with `git push remote refspec` by starting the *`refspec`* with a plus sign, but there's approximately a zero percent chance that you did this by accident.  There is also `--force-with-lease` which is like `--force` with a safety belt.

<sup>2</sup>You can limit the set of commits to be cloned, and when some commits are only found via special names (`refs/replace/` for instance, or pull request names specific to GitHub), some commits may not be copied by default.  But in general this is the way to think of clone, as copying the *commits*.

<sup>3</sup>Using `git clone --mirror` you can make Git copy the branch names directly, and there are other tricks that can make this false, but again, it's the way to *think* of cloning.

<sup>4</sup>In the bad old days of Git 1.5 or so, there were some bugs here.  I had work destroyed by `git pull`, more than once.